# Soft Body Loop Reset At Frame 1

Tags: soft-body

I have a character with soft body and I want to make simulation loop but every time when it goes to frame 1 simulations restart so it brokes my forever loop. How can I make loop and prevent simulation reset at frame 1 because it brokes my loop.

Comment: This is totally normal behaviour that the simulation restarts at frame 1. What did you expect? that it continues when it jumps back to frame 1? If you want to make a loop animation, just make sure that in your simulation your last frame looks exactly as frame 1. By this you will get a looping animation.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get a looping animation in Blender if you make sure that your last frame of your simulation looks the same (or nearly the same) as your first frame. Only by this you will get a looping animation.

Of course any simulation (rigid body, soft body or whatever) will restart at frame 1 (or at that frame the start frame of the simulation is set)